# Usar el valor de una variable dentro del string de una consulta

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

Normalmente cuando asigno una variable a una constante lo haría de la siguiente manera.

```vb
Dim user As Variant
user = InputBox("Ingresa tu usuario de la PC")
```

Ando conectando datos con Visual Basic y Access. En una parte de la consulta declaro la siguiente línea

```vb
MBEW.addWherePredicate ("BWTAR = '1234'")
```

¿Alguien me podría orientar para asignar la variable que ingreso en el input box al campo BWTAR?

Intenté haciéndolo así pero está mal

```vb
MBEW.addWherePredicate ("BWTAR = user")
```

Answer (score 1):

Encontre la forma, con un concatenado.
Por si alguien llega a pasar por lo mismo

```
MBEW.addWherePredicate ("BWTAR = '" & user & "'")
```